# how to get EST time alert in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

After Execute if($a) condition then view alert before 9 am "activate within 2 hr " and between 9am-6pm alert "wait 20min" and  after 6pm alert is "activate tommorow"

note: i was does not add any timestamp code i don't no knowledge of timestamps please provide EST timestamp code please fallow of above alerts sir

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once("db.php");

$simname = $_REQUEST["id"];
$sim_num = $_REQUEST["num"];
$name = $_SESSION['sasi_ad_name'];
$id = $_SESSION['sasi_ad_id'];

$query5=mysql_query("SELECT id, sim_number, phone_num, status, plan, add_on, features, Delear, Sub_Delear, T_C, sim_type FROM sims where sim_number='$sim_num' and sim_type='$simname'");

$query6=mysql_fetch_array($query5);
$delarname = $query6['Delear'];

$query7=mysql_query("SELECT id, name, Email, Phone, password, status, address, own, Identity_proof FROM adminusers WHERE name='$delarname'");

$query8=mysql_fetch_array($query7);
$demail = $query8['Email'];

$phone = $query8['Phone'];
$query2=mysql_query("SELECT id, name, Email, Phone, password, status, address, own, Identity_proof FROM adminusers WHERE status='0'");

$query3=mysql_fetch_array($query2);
$email = $query3['Email'];


if($_POST['submit'])
{
$subject="Activation Conformation SIM'";

$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$to  = $demail . ', '; // note the comma
$to .= $email;


// message

$message =  "<table align='left'>
        <tr height=20>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Delear Name : </b> $delarname</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>SIM Number : </b> $sim_num</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>SIM Type : </b> $simname </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Phone No : </b> $phone</td>
        </tr>

        <tr height=10>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr height=10>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Customer IP Address : </b> $ip</td>
        </tr>
        <tr height=20>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table> " ;


// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Additional headers
$headers .= 'To: Olpur <support@olpur.com>, Vegaitindia pvt ltd <contact@olpur.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Support Query <support@olpur.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: andesasi1222@gmail' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: andesasi1222@gmail' . "\r\n";

// Mail it
$a = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($a)
  {


        echo "<script> alert('THANK YOU…!! OUR TEAM WOULD SHORTLY CONTACT YOU'); window.location='../';</script>";

  }else{

        echo "<script> alert('Fail to save your information. Please re-enter your information'); window.location='index.php';</script>";
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're asking how to set a string to one of three possible values depending on the current time, then *none* of the code shown is relevant - we don't need to know about your request parameters or database queries or HTML. If you're asking how to do this in server-side PHP code then the "javascript" and "ajax" tags aren't relevant either.

Comment: for example client system time is 9am to 6pm  then i need alert "wait 20min" and client  system time is after 6pm give alert "activate tommorow "  i think using php code total process execute within if($a) condition please hope to replay my question